# No relations updated in the DB after writing symfony/doctrine associations

Tags: doctrine, symfony

So I am working on a project in symfony 3.0.1. I have generated entities (via `doctrine:generate:entity` with the following interactive setup questions) and then did the `doctrine:schema:update --force` to generate the tables in the DB from the Doctrine entities.
I then went in the entities and created associations.
After that I went ahead and did another `doctrine:schema:update -- force` and after checking in phpMyAdmin no relations were created by the schema update I forced.

Is there something else I am missing? See below my entities:

```
namespace MyAppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Logins
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="logins")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyAppBundle\Repository\LoginsRepository")
 */
class Logins
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="RoleID", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Roles", inversedBy="roleID")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="roleID", referencedColumnName="roleID")
 */
private $roleID;
```

'

```
'namespace MyAppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Roles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyAppBundle\Repository\RolesRepository")
 */
class Roles
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roleID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Logins", mappedBy="roleID")
     */
    private $roleID;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->roleID=new ArrayCollection();
```

Comment: Delete any files under Resources/config/doctrine.  They sometime get generated and will interfere with your annotations.

Comment: I don't have a doctrine folder or file in any of the config folders...
I looked in:
app/resources
app/config
src/MyAppBundle/resources/config

Comment: Review the relations documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html Trying to put a ManyToOne relation on an Id column makes no sense.

Comment: I corrected the text block as I had copied the annotations from the primary key Id property from Logins when I am not targeting that.
Basically on the DB side one roleID (primary key in Roles table)  can be present for many records from the Logins table.

Comment: Still looks like you are trying to make Roles:roleId be an primary key as well as an array.  Maybe try following the examples in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why there were conflicts, but I resolved my problem with Doctrine reverse engineering. I created the relations in PMA and then generated mapping from it. All worked out well.

EDIT: The guy in comments to my post was right. I cannot assign One-to-Many on an Identity property.

Answer (score 0):

I have had frustrating problems with relations not updating on my production environment several times now. My code would execute as expected with no errors, but the table(s) simply wouldn't update.

I've discovered that if you are using APC and you have just added a new relationship, you need to restart the web server in order for old versions of the entity classes to be flushed out.